Expo not loading app icon "No icon is defined in the Expo config."
my app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "myapp-native",
    "slug": "myapp-native",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    

I ran npx expo prebuild
It outputs a warning like this
» ios: icon: No icon is defined in the Expo config.
I searched the expo discord. Not a single other soul has encountered this warning, apparently. Searching it on quotes on google returns nothing either. I'm at a complete loss. The icon just will not appear in a dev build, ad hoc, or anything.
Am desperate for some help.

The warning is related to the way Expo handles app icons for iOS. While you’ve specified an icon in your app.json, this particular field only defines the icon for general purposes, such as Android and for the web. On the other hand, iOS requires a specific icon configuration, which needs to be defined under the ios key in your app.json. Add the ios.icon field in your app.json to ensure that an icon is set specifically for iOS.
Here’s how you can update your app.json:
{
  "expo": {
  "name": "myapp-native",
  "slug": "myapp-native",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
  "ios": {
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png"  // Add this line under ios
  },

References:
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#icon-2

Thanks that could have been explained a lot better in the error message
